# Change network category

Tags: networking, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall

My server has two network interfaces, one for public interface and one for internal management. These networks are completely isolated from each other. Both have own cables, routers and so on.

I'm trying to change the network category with the set-networkcategory cmdlet:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex 12 -NetworkCategory Public
```

What it does is, that it changes both interfaces to public category, although it should change only one specific category. What should I do differently, that I could change the interfaces separately?

EDIT:

Here is my powershell output:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetConnectionProfile

Name             : Network
InterfaceAlias   : Management
InterfaceIndex   : 13
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

Name             : Network
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
InterfaceIndex   : 12
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

PS C:\Users\Administrator> $profile = Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias Management
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $profile.NetworkCategory = "Private"
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $PROFILE

Name             : Network
InterfaceAlias   : Management
InterfaceIndex   : 13
NetworkCategory  : Private
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Set-NetConnectionProfile -InputObject $PROFILE
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetConnectionProfile

Name             : Network
InterfaceAlias   : Management
InterfaceIndex   : 13
NetworkCategory  : **Private**
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

Name             : Network
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
InterfaceIndex   : 12
NetworkCategory  : **Private**
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

As we can see, both interfaces have now new network category.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method for changing the network category of a network connection profile, referenced from the Microsoft [example documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj899565%28v=wps.630%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the `Set-NetConnectionProfile` cmdlet

---

- This first command gets the connection profile for the network adapter named `Ethernet1`. The command stores the results in the `$Profile` variable.

  `PS C:\> $Profile = Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias Ethernet1`
- This second command assigns the value of `Public` to the `NetworkCategory` property of the connection profile stored in the `$Profile` variable.

  `PS C:\> $Profile.NetworkCategory = Public`
- This third command sets the network category of the connection profile stored in the `$Profile` variable.

  `PS C:\> Set-NetConnectionProfile -InputObject $Profile`

or, a simple one-liner:

`Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "Management" | Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private`

Comment: I added Powershell output to question.

Comment: Did you try the method I posted?

Comment: Yes. I have tried that before asking the question. I tried that again, and it does not work.

Comment: Does `Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "Management" | Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private` result in the same outcome?

Comment: Yes it does. Also, Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex result the same outcome.